# MySQL Error Operand should contain 1 column during PREPARE Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS v1; 

SET @stmt_text = CONCAT('CREATE VIEW v1 AS SELECT (ID, PMID, Name, Address) FROM MyData
    LEFT JOIN My_Parameters USING (ID)
    WHERE MyData.ID > (newid) AND PMID > (PM_1)

PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt_text; 

EXECUTE stmt;
```

Note: v1 has 100 rows and 4 columns of data and the actual select has many 'joins'

DROP and SET statements execute without error but,

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt_text
Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: It looks like your `SET` statement is cut off -- where is the end of the quoted string, or the other arguments to `CONCAT`?

Comment: Remove the parentheses around the `SELECT` list.